# Haskell: using (fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1 == a / b) as guard?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and i don't understand why my guard won't accept it. here's my code. The guard should fire in case `b` is a divider of `a`.

```
gCF :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer;
gCF n p
    | (p <= 0 || n <= 0) = error "Input should be positive"
    | (p > n) = f p n
    | otherwise = f n p
    where 
        f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer;
        f a b
            | (fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1 == a / b) = b
            | otherwise = f a (b - 1)
```

Here's the error shown.

```
testscript.hs:168:28: error:
• No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
• In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
    ‘fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1’
  In the expression: (fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1 == a / b)
  In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 an equation for ‘f’:
    (fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1 == a / b)
    |
168 |                         | (fromInteger (a `div` b) / 1 == a / b) =      b     |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you make it the function more complex that necessary. Converting numbers between the `Int`eger and `Float`ing world can be dangerous, since it introduces rounding problems.

If I understand it correctly, you want to check if `a` is dividable by `b`. You can check this by verifying that `mod a b == 0`, and we are still in the integer worlds. So we can rewrite the program to:

```
gCF :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
gCF n p | p <= 0 || n <= 0 = error "Input should be positive"
        | p > n = f p n
        | otherwise = f n p
    where f a b | mod a b == 0 = b
                | otherwise = f a (b-1)
```

Since `a` does not change in the recursive calls, we can factor that out:

```
gCF :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
gCF n p | p <= 0 || n <= 0 = error "Input should be positive"
        | otherwise = f (min p n)
    where a = max p n
          f b | mod a b == 0 = b
              | otherwise = f (b-1)
```

We can also generalize the signature to let it work with any `Integral` type:

```
gCF :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
gCF n p | p <= 0 || n <= 0 = error "Input should be positive"
        | otherwise = f (min p n)
    where a = max p n
          f b | mod a b == 0 = b
              | otherwise = f (b-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution!

```
gCF :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer;
gCF n p
    | (p <= 0 || n <= 0) = error "Input should be positive"
    | (p > n) = floor (f (fromInteger p) (fromInteger n) (fromInteger n))
    | otherwise = floor (f (fromInteger n) (fromInteger p) (fromInteger p))
    where 
        f :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float;
        f a b c
            | (fromInteger (floor (a / c)) == a / c) && (fromInteger (floor (b / c)) == b / c) = c
            | otherwise = f a b (c - 1)
```